# How to use setTimeout method to move carousel after specified time? Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, settimeout

I have a div with 3 images next to each other.
Initially 1 image is displayed while the other 2 are hidden using overflow:hidden on a parent div.
Then i use setInterval method to move the div with the images 1px to the left every milisecond until the div has moved 150px to the left.
By that time the first image has moved out of view due to overflow:hidden and the second image is now in view. At this point it pauses for a second, as intended, using setTimeout method. But then things start to go wrong. After the 1 sec has elapsed...the third image either speeds up and stops where it should....or it speeds up and goes beyond the stopping point and out of view. Then the more you click the button the images just start to disappear! I dont think im using setTimeout correctly. When i watch it in the debugger...the function that setTimeout calls (pause() ) loops over and over at random intervals before moving on through the rest of the script. Then comes back to loop again randomly. It should only run once...1 sec after setTimeout calls it, then never again.

```js
function move() {
    var element = document.getElementById('mover');
    var pos = -300;
    var go = setInterval(animate, 1);
    
    function animate() {
        if (pos === 0) {
            clearInterval(go);
        } else if (pos === -150) {
            function pause() {
                pos++;
            }
            setTimeout(pause, 1000);
            
        } else {
            pos++;
            element.style.left = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
}

#overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    height: 225px;
}

#mover {
    position: relative;
    left: -300px;
    width: 450px;
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="overflow">
            <div id="mover">
                <img src="http://images.primewire.ag/thumbs/2763151_Mr_Robot_2015_30.jpg">
                <img src="http://images.primewire.ag/thumbs/2777450_Outcast_2016.jpg">
                <img src="http://images.primewire.ag/thumbs/2770130_Ash_vs_Evil_Dead_1969.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <br>
        <button onclick="move()">Click me</button>
```

Sorry im a complete beginner and i know there must be things i havent considered. Could someone please tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Because you are using setTimeout which is asynchronous, it may be possible (I'm not sure) for pos never to equal 0 or 150 at the exact moment that the check is called. How about replacing the equals with greater than or equal to try and avoid that situation? That might stop the part where it randomly goes past the position it is supposed to.

Comment: @Davis Thanks for the tip! Using greater than or equal sorted out the bug at the end of the slide. Now i have a better idea of whats going on. Ill keep thinking about it now that i have your info to work with. Really appreciate it :)

Comment: Glad that I could help fix that problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but hopefully there's something useful here:

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/g01zd64o/17/

jQuery:

```
var move = function() {
  var element = document.getElementById('mover');
  var pos = element.offsetLeft;

  if (pos != 0) {
        setTimeout(function() {
      element.style.left = pos + 150 + 'px';
    }, 1000);
  } 
}
```

Note: it wasn't clear to me why some of your javascript is there, I might be missing something. I've tried to create a minimal representation.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sorry my javascript is unclear. Im a total noob struggling to make sense of it all atm. But what i am trying to do is...at a single click of the button, id like the first image to slide out of sight to the right....then pause at the second image.....then have the second image slide to the right....and stop at the third image. What im really trying to replicate is a version of the sliding images that can be seen at [primewire](http://www.primewire.ag/?tv) ..very top of the screen. Ive seen css transition before but wanted to try and learn to animate something myself.

Comment: Well i tried everything using my method and it didnt work out in the end. So i adopted a variation of your method to get the result i needed. Thanks for pointing me in a better direction :)

Comment: That's great. If you found my answer useful, I'd appreciate it if you could mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I've ticked the green tick next to your answer. But I can't vote it up because my rep too low. Says my feedback has been recorded but won't be publicly displayed :(